# Factory pattern with dependency injection, serviceProvider always return null

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, service, factory-pattern

I tried to follow the example from
https://chaitanyasuvarna.wordpress.com/2021/03/21/factory-pattern-di-in-net-core/
but i didn't use a classic console application, I created a .Net core service project in VS.

Please find below the files with their source code:

IShape.cs

```
public interface IShape
{
    public void GetInputValues();
    public void DisplaySurfaceArea();
    public void DisplayVolume();
}
```

Sphere.cs

```
public class Sphere : IShape
{
    public decimal Radius { get; set; }

    public void GetInputValues()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Radius : ");
        Radius = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    public void DisplaySurfaceArea()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Surface Area of the sphere is :" + (4 * 3.14m * Radius * Radius));
    }

    public void DisplayVolume()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Volume of the sphere is :" + (4 / 3 * 3.14m * Radius * Radius * Radius));
    }
}
```

Cube.cs

```
public class Cube : IShape
{
    public decimal Side { get; set; }

    public void GetInputValues()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Side : ");
        Side = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    public void DisplaySurfaceArea()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Surface Area of the Cube is :" + (6 * Side * Side));
    }

    public void DisplayVolume()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Volume of the Cube is :" + (Side * Side * Side));
    }
}
```

ShapeFactory.cs

```
public class ShapeFactory : IShapeFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;


    public ShapeFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public IShape GetShape(ShapeEnum shapeEnum)
    {
        switch (shapeEnum)
        {
            case ShapeEnum.Cube:
                return (IShape)this.serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(Cube));
            case ShapeEnum.Sphere:
                return (IShape)this.serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(Sphere));
            default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(shapeEnum), shapeEnum, $"Shape of {shapeEnum} is not supported.");
        }
    }
}

public interface IShapeFactory
{
    public IShape GetShape(ShapeEnum shapeEnum);
}
```

ShapeCalculationService.cs

```
public class ShapeCalculationService : IShapeCalculationService
{
    private readonly IShapeFactory _shapeFactory;
    private IShape _shape;

    public ShapeCalculationService(IShapeFactory shapeFactory)
    {
        this._shapeFactory = shapeFactory;
    }

    public void CalculateShapeMeasurements()
    {
        this._shape = GetShapeFromUser();
        this._shape.GetInputValues();
        this._shape.DisplaySurfaceArea();
        this._shape.DisplayVolume();
    }

    private IShape GetShapeFromUser()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the serial no. for the shape you want to choose :");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Cube");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Sphere");
        var serialNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        switch (serialNumber)
        {
            case 1:
                return _shapeFactory.GetShape(ShapeEnum.Cube);
            case 2:
                return _shapeFactory.GetShape(ShapeEnum.Sphere);
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Invalid input.");
        }
    }
}

public interface IShapeCalculationService
{
    public void CalculateShapeMeasurements();
}
```

worker.cs

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
    private readonly IShapeCalculationService shapeCalculationService;
    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IShapeCalculationService shapeCalculationService)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        this.shapeCalculationService = shapeCalculationService;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            
            shapeCalculationService.CalculateShapeMeasurements();
            _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
            await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```cs
using TestFactory;

IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext,services) =>
    {
        services.AddTransient<IShapeFactory, ShapeFactory>();
        services.AddTransient<IShapeCalculationService, ShapeCalculationService>();
        services.AddScoped<Sphere>().AddScoped<IShape, Sphere>(s=>s.GetService<Sphere>());
        services.AddScoped<Cube>().AddScoped<IShape, Cube>(s => s.GetService<Cube>()); ;
        
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
    })
    .Build();

await host.RunAsync();
```

While going through with the debugger, I found that
`public IShape GetShape(ShapeEnum shapeEnum)` always returns null.

Please can you advice what I am doing wrong, and how I can correct it and make the example work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your solution by using delegate in DI, like this:

```
{
    public delegate IShape ShapeResolver(int serialNumber);
}
```

then in program.cs:

```
services.AddScoped<Sphere>();
services.AddScoped<Cube>();

 services.AddTransient<ShapeResolver>(serviceProvider => key =>
            {
                switch (key)
                {
                    case 1:
                        return this.serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<Cube>();

                    case 2:
                        return this.serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<Sphere>();

                    default:
                        throw new KeyNotFoundException();
                }
```

ShapeCalculationService will look something like this:

```
public class ShapeCalculationService : IShapeCalculationService
{
    private readonly ShapeResolver _ShapeResolver;
    private IShape _shape;

    public ShapeCalculationService(ShapeResolver shapeResolver)
    {
        this._ShapeResolver= shapeResolver;
    }

    public void CalculateShapeMeasurements()
    {
        this._shape = GetShapeFromUser();
        this._shape.GetInputValues();
        this._shape.DisplaySurfaceArea();
        this._shape.DisplayVolume();
    }

    private IShape GetShapeFromUser()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the serial no. for the shape you want to choose :");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Cube");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Sphere");
        var serialNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        return _ShapeResolver(serialNumber);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You registered and requested different types. Within your registration phase you make these calls to register your types by their interfaces:

```
services.AddScoped<Sphere>().AddScoped<IShape, Sphere>(s=>s.GetService<Sphere>());
services.AddScoped<Cube>().AddScoped<IShape, Cube>(s => s.GetService<Cube>());
```

Within your method later you are going to request this:

```
(IShape)this.serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(Cube))
```

As you can see, the type `Cube` is not registered within the DI Container, only its interface `IShape`. Also it seems you seem to mix up the things a little bit, cause the purpose of a registered factory is to support the DI framework to produce the desired concrete type. But your factory just forwards the calls to the container itself.

To make your code working you should in a first step register your `Sphere` and `Cube` as their explicit type within the DI like this:

```
services.AddScoped<Sphere>();
services.AddScoped<Cube>();
```

And within your factory you should call one of these:

```
(IShape)this.serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(typeof(Cube));
this.serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<Cube>();
```

In a next step take a closer look on how factories are implemented and how they  know which concrete type they have to return for a given interface or base type.

### Update regarding scopes

I just seen now, that you registered your classes as *scoped*, but in your code you're going to ask the provider directly for an instance. This is the *root* provider that doesn't hold a scope. Instead you have to create a scope by calling `.CreateScope()` and from the returned scoped provider you can request an instance of your desired scoped classes. For further details take a look at the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection).

Comment: Hi,I added the services.AddScoped<Sphere>(); and services.AddScoped<Cube>(); to the Program.cs, but the issue remains. The call this.serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(typeof(Cube)) is not working because it requires a cast to IShape

Comment: If you use the non-generic method with a type parameter, the return type is object and you have to cast it. If you use the generic method with the corresponding parameter the return type is of this type T and a cast shouldn't be necessary. Using the *Required* method prevents returning null and will throw an exception. If it doesn't work, it should probably give you a hint, why it doesn't return anything.